# Why is Usage reporting Camera and Photos using so much space?

Tags: ipad, photo-stream, disk-space

On my iPad 3, if I check Usage the system reports that Camera and Photos, and specifically the Photostream, is consuming nearly 5GB of space.  I have turned off the Photostream to verify but it only frees about 100MB.  I do not even have that many photos so don't see where the space is being used.
How can I regain all this used space?

Update: I have also tried to simply delete the entry by swiping and choosing "Delete" but, despite some freezing of the screen, it does not appear to do anything.